# PS3 Data Management

Tags: ps3

I've had a 160 GB PS3 for almost 3 years now, and would like to back up my data in case something happens to the console, particularly if I get a YLOD(which would totally suck, as I *really* love my PsTriple).

I have definitely considered creating a FAT32 partition on my 500GB external hard drive just for that purpose, but would that work okay.....or would I have to format the *entire* drive(which I can't afford to do at the moment)?

Also, if I end up losing the games & other content that I bought and downloaded, would I have to pay for them all over again, or is it something I needn't be worried about?(I can handle just re-downloading; I got a decent cable speed, so that'll be fine)

And finally, I've heard a lotta great things about PSN Plus, including the ability to save game data, as well as trophies and saves. But will it be able to transfer the backup data to a new PS3 incase the old one dies and the original stuff can no longer be recovered by ordinary means?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a partition, there is no need to format whole drive.

Yes, you can redownload all your games.

PS+ save game data is only for your saved games, trophies are associated with your account, and as long as they synchronized you can't lose anything. And yes, you can restore all that to new console.